# how to test a simple stack class using pytest

Tags: python, pytest

im trying to write a simple stack class to learn about TDD. but the problem is it fails to pass a test using the right code.

here is the code:

```
class Stack:
    def __init__(self):
        self.stack = []

    def push(self,new_item):
        self.stack.append(new_item)

    def pop(self):
        return int(self.stack.pop(0))
```

and here is the test class:

```
import pytest
from Stack import Stack

def test_it_can_push():
    stack = Stack()
    stack.push(2)
    assert stack.stack is [2]
```

and here is the error:

```
    def test_it_can_push():
        stack = Stack()
        stack.push(2)
>       assert stack.stack is [2]
E       assert [2] is [2]
E        +  where [2] = <Stack.Stack instance at 0x7f2273491560>.stack

test_stack.py:7: AssertionError
```

can someone please, tell me how to fix this problem?

Comment: Use `assert stack.stack == [2]`

Comment: As a side note, you are importing `pytest` but you are not using it.

Answer (score 1):

You're doing the identity check (`id` -- memory location in CPython) using `is`, which will never be equal as the operands are two different lists (which are mutable objects), although they have the same elements, and you can check with `id`.

Do equity test:

```
assert stack.stack == [2]
```

Comment: Two list operands can be equal using `is`, e.g: `a = [1,2,3]; b = a; assert b is a`

Comment: @Perplexabot They are the same list i.e. both names `a` and `b` refer to the same list object. Check with `id`.

Comment: They are the same list, true. But you say "...which will never be equal given the operands are lists" which is not true, or at least the wording is confusing. The example I gave in my previous comment proves that statement wrong: both operands are lists, yet `is` returns `true`

Comment: @Perplexabot Fair enough. Rephrased.